# input type date min and max values validate against yyyy-mm-dd instead of dd-mm-yyyy

Tags: html, validation

I am using the date input type in HTML5.
It is displaying the correctly in the format dd-MM-yyyy.
However the min and max values does not validate correctly, because it validates against the format yyyy-MM-dd.
I have not been able to change the format the min and max values validates, any ideas?

```
<input type="date" name="DateName" id="DateID" min="2000-01-01" max="2100-12-31"/>
```

Comment: Why can't you change the values for min and max?

Comment: Works fine for me in Chromium.

Comment: The date is displayed as: dd-MM-yyyy. However when I try to edit the date for example to 22.01.2013 and then presses submit it moves the cursor to the DateID field. There is no error message, it just moves the cursor to the DateID field and does not move on.

min and max written as dd-MM-yyyy does not work

Comment: @CasperThuleHansen: This could very well be a browser bug. What browser and OS are you using?

Comment: I have tested with chrome browser: Version 27.0.1453.116 m
and internet explorer: 9.0.8112.16421

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The attributes `value`, `min` and `max` have the same format for dates. They follow the [RFC 3339](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3339) where the full data syntax is as:

```
full-date       = date-fullyear "-" date-month "-" date-mday
date-fullyear   = 4DIGIT
date-month      = 2DIGIT  (01-12)
date-mday       = 2DIGIT  (01-28, 01-29, 01-30, 01-31)
```

So even if the browser displays you the date in format `dd-mm-yyyy` internally it's using this syntax.

Anyway, this HTML5 input type is only supported in Safari, Chrome and Opera.

You can try this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zLKmx/) with invalid dates as 12/12/2014, when you submit the form an error message is displayed.

Comment: How to I change the format displayed then before it validates against the yyyy-mm-dd?

Comment: @CasperThuleHansen: Most likely you can't. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17443034/input-type-date-min-and-max-values-validate-against-yyyy-mm-dd-instead-of-dd-mm

Comment: @CasperThuleHansen the browser is validating using yyyy-mm-dd, and you cannot change the format displayed...

Comment: @JonathanNaguin how do I find the demo_form.asp?

Comment: @CasperThuleHansen you don't need it, if the form is submitted, then the data is valid...

Comment: The display format is definied by the users system settings. In windows you could change this in 'control panel (Systemsteuerung)' in Menü "Region and Language".